# Type Error in Alloy specification

Tags: requirements, alloy

In the Requirements Engineering (2007) article, "Requirement Progression In Problem Frames", there is a worked example on a traffic lights problem that I have transcribed into the Alloy editor. Unfortunately, I get the following error when testing the code.

Starting the solver...

A type error has occurred:
This must be a set or relation.
Instead, it has the following possible type(s):
{PrimitiveBoolean}

The error is triggered by the following predicate:

```
pred LightUnitBreadcrumb [] {
    all t: Time | 
        NGObserve [t] <=> 
            odd [NGPulse [t]] and
        SGObserve [t] <=> 
            odd [SGPulse [t]] }
```

referencing the NGPulse predicate below:

```
sig NGP, SGP, NRP, SRP in Time {}
pred NGPulse [t: Time] {t in NGP}
pred SGPulse [t: Time] {t in SGP}
pred NRPulse [t: Time] {t in NRP}
pred SRPulse [t: Time] {t in SRP}
```

Comment: Exactly. I explain on page 137 of my [book](http://softwareabstractions.org) why boolean is not a type in Alloy.

Comment: Thanks to both Loic and Daniel for follow-ups and clarifications - much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that a set-valued expression is expected between the square brackets of `odd` instead of calls to the `NGPulse` or `SGPulse` predicates. Indeed, predicates are boolean-valued and not set/relation valued expressions, hence the error.